# Why pascal can't write boolean value

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have a code:

```pascal
for i:=0 to High(a) do
begin 
    { I want to write 0 and 1 represent for true and false }
    writeln(i % 2 = 0);
end;
```

But the line with "writeln" occurs error

```
Syntax error, ")" expected but "ordinal const" found
```

anyone can help me? :(

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pascal/Delphi, the modulus operator is `mod`:

```
writeln(i mod 2 = 0);
```

`%` is not a Pascal/Delphi operator at all.

Hence, this has nothing to do with the `Writeln` procedure not accepting booleans.

---

This will print `FALSE` or `TRUE`. If you want `0` or `1`, you need `Ord(i mod 2 = 0)` or, even nicer, `Ord(not Odd(i))`.

Comment: oh, sorry for my mistake :(. 
I have changed it but i have another question: that line code write to console "True/False" instead of "0, 1". How can I convert it?

Comment: Just beware that `Ord(b)` only is guaranteed to yield `0` or `1` if `b` is a true boolean. If it is some other kind of boolean, like `ByteBool`, `WordBool` or has been obtained by simply casting an integer value, it might be something completely different. If this is not good enough for you, you can trivially create a function that takes a boolean in any form and returns the integer `0` or `1`. (But this is a different topic.)